# Warning message in predict.gam - why is this happening?

Tags: r

Reference: Page 22 of, http://www.statoek.wiso.uni-goettingen.de/mitarbeiter/ogi/pub/r_workshop.pdf

My question is self-contained in this post though. The data is in `http://134.76.173.220/R_workshop`

```
car <- read.table("car.dat", header = TRUE)
attach(car)

library(mgcv)
fit <- gam(MPG~s(SP))


plot(HP, MPG)
x <- seq(0, 350, length = 500)
y <- predict(fit, data.frame(HP = x))
lines(x, y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

Error im receiving:

```
Warning message:
In predict.gam(fit, data.frame(HP = x)) :
  not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
```

Comment: try `y <- predict(fit, data.frame(SP = x))`

Comment: In my understanding, SO is not a forum to spot code errors. At least the way you've crafted your title, it is likely to elicit down-votes. I'd advice you to change the title to something more appropriate and useful for the future (Something like: "Warning message in predict.gam - why is this happening")

Comment: Thanks @Arun, ive changed the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work if you scrap the 'attach' adjust the code accordingly and use SP as suggested by @GeorgeDontas

```
fit <- gam(MPG~s(SP), data=car)

plot(car$HP, car$MPG)
x <- seq(0, 350, length = 500)
y <- predict(fit, data.frame(SP = x))
lines(x, y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to never, ever, ever use `attach`.  It causes too many obscure bugs.

Comment: This is correct.. but I think it is supposed to be MPG~HP because that produces a decent fit, whilst MPG~SP produces a terrible wobbly overfit

Comment: @StephenHenderson i did the same thing too, except i put plot(SP, MPG) instead of changing the regression. i think Ed G meant to do the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supposed to be MPG~HP as that is a good fit and SP is poor (with default parameters)

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

fit <- gam(MPG~s(SP), data=car)
plot(car$SP, car$MPG)
x <- seq(0, 350, length = 500)
y <- predict(fit, data.frame(SP = x))
lines(x, y, col = "red", lwd = 2)

fit <- gam(MPG~s(HP), data=car)
plot(car$HP, car$MPG)
x <- seq(0, 350, length = 500)
y <- predict(fit, data.frame(HP = x))
lines(x, y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: bad fit and good fit]

Comment: (+1) Hey Stephen, youre right but the actual problem was with attach(cars). I think Ed G meant to write plot(SP, MPG), instead of (HP, MPG).

Comment: yeah sorry I'm just being an awful pedant.